# Foundation - Full width with Explorer issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation

I'm experimenting Foundation and I wanted to build a template with full width rows. Everything is working fine on Firefox and Chrome but full width is not working on IE (I'm using IE 11 so I guess previous versions are also impacted).

My html:

```
<div class="row fullWidth-3">
    <div class="small-12 columns navigation-3">Navigation</div>
    <div class="small-12 columns advertising-3">
        Advertising
        <div class="contentWidth-3">
            <div class="small-12 columns">TEST</div>
            <div class="medium-4 columns">TEST</div>
            <div class="medium-8" columns">TEST</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now the CSS part:

```
.fullWidth-3
    {
       width: 100%;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       max-width: initial;
    }

.contentWidth-3
    {

        width: 85%;
        margin:0 auto;
        color:#000;
        background-color:#FFF;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }   

.navigation-3
    {
        background-color:#000;
        color:#FFF;
        margin:0px;
        padding:5px;
        box-sizing:border-box; 
        font-size:19px;
    }

.advertising-3
    {
        background-color:#999;
        color:#FFF;
        margin:0px;
        padding:5px;
        box-sizing:border-box; 
        font-size:19px;
    }
```

IE seems to be limited around 1000 pixels width while Firefox and Chrome displaying a full width div as expected.

I'd like to keep the foundation CSS clean. Do you have any idea of how I could solve this?

additional note:
- with this alone, it doesn't work either

```
.fullWidth-3
    {
       width: 100%;
    }
```

[image: SCREENSHOT WITH IE11]
[image: SCREENSHOT WITH FF39]

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: `max-width:initial` ? What happens if you remove that? Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to *reproduce it ***in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Paulie, if I stripped it down to the minimum (see additional note), it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Then we need a demo of this *not* working so we can tinker with it.

Comment: Class "row" has a general max-width limit http://prntscr.com/7z8pt1 62.5rem for all browsers, remove max-width:initial from .fullWidth-3 and you'll see the same behaviour as in IE. Rather set max-width:100% than leave initial thing, that is not consistent across browsers

Comment: Great! It works, thanks GL!!

Comment: Yeah...just found that max-width issue. @GL.awog I suggest you post that as an answer.

Comment: I can't mark your comment as correct answer for my question, can you post it separately so that I can mark it as "solved" ? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @GL.awog

> Class "row" has a general max-width limit of 62.5rem for all browsers, remove max-width:initial from .fullWidth-3 and you'll see the same behaviour as in IE.
>
> Rather set max-width:100% than leave initial thing, that is not consistent across browser